# Selecting that pixel that minimizes the distance

Tags: matlab, select, pixel, distance, minimize

Say I have the following two matrices:

```
>> x = [1 4 3; 6 4 3; 6 9 3; 2 4 3; 5 4 0; 5 3 1; 6 4 7];
>> y = [0 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 1 0; 0 1 1; 0.2 0.8 0.54; 1 1 1; 0 0 0];
```

Where you can think of `x` as some image, and `y` as the **degree of membership** of each element of `x` to some region of interest.

Say I set those elements in `x` that have degree of membership = 1 to `1` (**core**) and the other elements to `0` as follows:

```
x = zeros(size(y));
x(y==1) = 1;
```

In which case I will have the following output:

```
     0     0     1
     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     0     1     1
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
     0     0     0
```

Now, for the elements of `0`, I substitute their values with the value of `y` in the corresponding location as follows:

```
x(x==0)=y(x==0);
```

Now, I select those pixels that are considered `4-neighbours` of `core` but not in core as follows:

```
four_neighbourhood_pixels = imdilate(core, strel('diamond', 1)) - core;
```

My question is: **how can we select a pixel `p` that belongs to `four_neighbourhood_pixels` that minimizes the distance between `x` & `core`**?

Provided that for distance I calculate it as follows:

```
pdist([x,core],'minkowski');
```

Provided that `x` in the preceding command will be the matrix after substituting the `zeros` with the degree of membership values `y` i the corresponding location?

So, how can I select that pixel that belongs to `four_neighbourhood_pixels` that minimizes the distance between `x` with the zeros substituted and `core`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `core` is the following matrix:

```
 0     0     1
 1     1     0
 1     1     0
 0     1     1
 0     0     0
 1     1     1
 0     0     0
```

First find the distance between `x` and `core`.

```
dist=pdist([x,core],'minkowski');
dist1=squareform(dist);
[row1,row2]=find(dist1==min(dist1(:)); %interpretation: you get the minimum distance  between row1 and row2 of [x core]
```

Veify if my understanding is correct:

You want a pixel from x which minimizes the distance `dist` and it should belong to `four_neighbourhood_pixels`. This is the matrix `[x core]`

```
 1     4     3     0     0     1
 6     4     3     1     1     0
 6     9     3     1     1     0
 2     4     3     0     1     1
 5     4     0     0     0     0
 5     3     1     1     1     1
 6     4     7     0     0     0
```

Suppose you get the minimum value between 2nd row and 3rd row. Now based on this tell us what you mean by "find a pixel which minimizes..."